# Get paragraph text inside specified paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="items" onclick="myfunction()">
<p id="item">a</p>
<p id="item">b</p>
<p id="item">c</p>
<p id="item">d</p>
<p id="item">e</p>
</div>

function myfunction() {
var r = document.getElementById("item").innerHTML;
alert(r);
}
```

When i click 'a', pop up and shown 'a', but when i click b, pop up and shown 'a' again! where is the missing?

Comment: You have same `id` attribute values. Each `id` must be unique in a document.

Comment: This is because `getElementById` will just grab the first component with the ID in the HTML component tree. You can instead add this function to every `<p>` element to alert its inner HTML.

Comment: the element with `id="item"` still have the `innerHTML` "a"

Comment: If you have the opportunity to work with jQuery this could be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the original element that triggered the event, you should use something like this:

```
<div id="items" onclick="myfunction(event);">

function myfunction(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var tar = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    // Should probably check that the tar element is a <p> and has the specific id/class
    var val = tar.innerHTML;
    alert(val);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GtfDf/

On a similar note, unique `id` attributes are required in order for `getElementById` to work properly, and for valid HTML. Another option is to bind an event to each `<p>` element, and instead of using `id`, use `class`. Like this:

```
<div id="items">
    <p class="item">a</p>
    <p class="item">b</p>
    <p class="item">c</p>
    <p class="item">d</p>
    <p class="item">e</p>
</div>

window.onload = function () {
    var items_div = document.getElementById("items");
    var items = items_div.querySelectorAll(".item");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].onclick = myfunction;
    }
};

function myfunction() {
    var val = this.innerHTML;
    alert(val);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eWZyn/1/

But there are many options/alternatives for using the `getElementById`/`querySelectorAll`, and may or may not be better.

The first example is "better" for dynamic items being added/removed from the div. The second example seems more appropriate, in my opinion, for static items. I only say that in case there are other elements inside the div that could be handled for the click event. Either way, I hope these example help.

Comment: I wouldn't say *besides the fact* necessarily...because this is the correct answer. Simply adding unique IDs wouldn't fix OP's code. +1 to you

Comment: @nbrooks You're right, I think I worded it incorrectly. More or less, I meant something like "At the same time, `id`s should be unique" and was unrelated to immediately fixing the problem. Anyways, I updated with more information, which may or may not help

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.

```
<div id="items">
<p onclick="myfunction(this)">a</p>
<p onclick="myfunction(this)">b</p>
<p onclick="myfunction(this)">c</p>
<p onclick="myfunction(this)">d</p>
<p onclick="myfunction(this)">e</p>
</div>
<script>
function myfunction(a) {
var r = a.innerHTML;
alert(r);
}
</script>
```

Comment: So if I have more and more `<p>`s components I should add the `onclick="someFunction()"` manually for all of them too?

Comment: Just one way to get it work. May not be the best way !!

Comment: I've posted an answer to avoid all that boilerplate copy/paste on every `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate the event handling to the container div and use the target (or srcElement, in IE 8 and below)
to return the text of the clicked paragraph. innerHTML might not be the best choice, since paragraphs can have 
spans and other inline html tags and attributes as well as text.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>test page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<p>c</p>
<p>d</p>
<p>e</p>
</div>

<script>
function myfunction(e) {
    e=e||window.event;
    var who=e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(who.tagName=='P'){
        alert(who.textContent || who.innerText || '');
    }
}
onload=function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].onclick=myfunction;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```